# Default fstab mount options

Tags: fstab

On a clean [Ubuntu 11.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29) (Natty Narwhal) installation, I used just a single partition for everything. The line that got added in the fstab file is this

```
UUID=xxx     /      ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
```

Shouldn't there be a '**defaults**' in there?

I've bumped into this while trying to move the home folder to a different partition. I've done it, and everything is working fine. I've added only `errors=remount-ro` in the fstab line for `/home`.

Now I'm in the process of 'securing' it, and choosing those options more wisely (like adding nodev and nosuid). So, do I need to add 'defaults' or not? Why is it not added?

*Which specific options are the 'defaults' anyway in Natty Narwhal?*

Do I need to add

```
UUID=xxx /home ext4 nodev,nosuid,errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

or

```
UUID=xxx /home ext4 defaults,nodev,nosuid,error=remount-ro 0 2
```

or something else?

Also, I've seen that relatime is in the defaults for Natty Narwhal. But are the defaults running if there is no mention of the defaults keyword in fstab and the 'mount' output?

Answer (score 20):

As per `man mount` (if you use the option `defaults`):

```
   defaults
          Use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.
```

When you use contradicting options (like `defaults,noexec`), the later will take precedence.

If you don't state any options, the default options in Ubuntu are `rw,relatime`.

Comment: So, to understand it better: When an entry has just `errors=remount-ro` does this translate to `rw,relatime, errors=remount-ro` or `rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async,errors=remount-ro`? I was starting to get the impression that if 'defaults' is not explicitly mentioned, it is implied anyway, and it was removed from the fstab default configuration because of redundancy if other options exist.

Comment: The former, i.e. `rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro`. When you mount something, you can check its mount options by issuing the command `mount` or `cat /proc/mounts`.

Comment: Something is not right. I just tested it: When my fstab has `nodev,nosuid,errors=remount-ro` for /home, then `cat /proc/mounts` returns `rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered` as options. If I edit the fstab and add the defaults keyword, so it is `defaults,nodev,nosuid,errors=remount-ro` then after a reboot, `cat /proc/mounts` returns exactly the same as the previously. The `defaults` when added to fstab changes nothing, at least in /proc/mounts. What is going on?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. As per `man mount` again: *Some of these options could be enabled or disabled by default in the system kernel. To check the current setting see the options in /proc/mounts.* It's better to list the desired options one by one and check its availability.

Comment: Also `man 8 mount` says for the `error` attribute available for `ext2` that `The default is set in the filesystem superblock, and can be changed using tune2fs(8)`